# Segmentation fault when initializing pointer to char array

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to write a program that reads text from a file, converts the characters to uppercase and then writes the output on a new file. The code works just fine for the reading and converting to uppercase parts, but for the writing the output part when I create a `char*` for the name of the output file, I get a segmentation fault.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void lowerToUpper(char* temp)
{
    char* name;
    name = strtok(temp,":");

    // Convert to upper case
    char* s = name;
    while (*s)
    {
        *s = toupper((unsigned char) *s);
        s++;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int fd;
    char* file_name_read = "./test.txt";
    fd = open(file_name_read, O_RDONLY);
    char* buf_rd;

    ssize_t nr;
    size_t byte_count = 1000;
    off_t offset = 0;

    nr = pread(fd, buf_rd, byte_count, offset);

    close(fd);

    lowerToUpper(buf_rd);

    char* file_name_write = "./test_uppercase.txt";

    /* CODE FOR WRITING TO THE FILE */

    return 0;
}
```

When I remove the `char* file_name_write` line, the code works fine. When I include it in the code, I get a segmentation fault.

I have tried

- removing the call to the `lowerToUpper()` inside `main`
- using `char file_name_write[]` instead of `char* file_name_write`
- using `malloc()` to allocate space and then assign its value
- using different `byte_count` and `offset` values

**Edit:**
The problem was an uninitialized pointer with `buf_rd`. When I added

```
char* buf_rd = (char*) malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
```

it solved the problem.

Thank you Mr Lister and lurker!

Comment: Where do you initialise buf_rd?

Comment: @MrLister It gets initialized in pread(). I also tried initializing it with NULL and other temporary values but the problem still continues.

Comment: @OmerFY no it doesn't. `pread` expects you to pass a valid buffer pointer. `buf_rd` doesn't hold a valid buffer pointer. It's an uninitialized pointer. Initializing it with NULL will cause `pread` to attempt to write to address NULL, which is bad. Unclear what "other temporary values" means in your context. And you said you have tried using `malloc` but haven't shown exactly what/how you did that.

Comment: @lurker I tried using malloc for the file_name_write but now I have tried it with buf_rd and it solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: You need something like `buf_rd = malloc(byte_count * sizeof *buf_rd);` before calling `pread`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char* buf_rd;
...
nr = pread(fd, buf_rd, byte_count, offset);
```

You did not allocate memory for `buf_rd`. It is just a pointer.

Comment: I noticed that and I already updated the answer. Thanks, though ;) I wrote the answer before re-reading the docs for `strtok()`.

Answer (score 1):

You use `buf_rd` as buffer, but that variable is only declared and never initialized.

The [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html) says:

> **ssize_t pread(int** *fd* **, void *** *buf* **, size_t** *count* **, off_t** *offset* **);**
>
> **pread()** reads up to *count* bytes from file descriptor *fd* at offset
>   *offset* (from the start of the file) into the buffer starting at *buf*.
>   The file offset is not changed.

It is expected of you to initialize the a buffer that can be used by the `pread` function.